# How can I create a MySQL database from a Perl script?

Tags: mysql, database, perl, dbi

I'm trying to create a database in Perl but it keeps trying to ask me for a database to use.
Here's my code:

```
my @db_months = qw(JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC);

foreach my $db_month (@db_months)
{
  ## create db
  my $db_name = $db_month.$Year;
  my $dbh = DBI->connect($dns, $user, $password) or die "Unable to connect: $DBI::errstr\n"; 
  my $row = $dbh->do("CREATE DATABASE '".$db_name."' DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;"); 
  $dbh->disconnect(); 
}
```

Please help.

Comment: What does `$dns` contain? What error do you get?

Comment: In this context, a better nomenclature for `$dns` would be `$dsn`.

Comment: Agreed. In general, DNS = Domain Name System and DSN = Data Source Name.

Comment: As others have said, what line throws an error, and what is the error?  Also, a table for every month?  It sounds like you're doing database schemas all wrong, unless you have a very unusual requirement which makes that necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Just simply omit the `database=$database;`:

```
$dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:host=$host;port=$port", $user, $pw);
$dbh->do("create database test") or die "Cannot create database \n ";
```

Answer (score 1):

It really helps to know which line is giving an error and what precisely the error is.

Try using backticks (`) instead of single quotes (') around the database name...

Answer (score 0):

The [server administration function](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD%3a%3amysql#Server_Administration) of [`DBD::mysql`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD%3a%3amysql) can be used:

```
my $rc = $dbh->func( 'createdb', $db_name, 'admin' );
```

Comment: Can I specify collation with createdb? I haven't found it in DBD/mysql.pm

Comment: No, you can't. I'm really not a fan of this part of DBD::mysql.